# Image rotating after CIFilter

Tags: swift, ciimage

I'm applying a CIFilter to a portrait image. For some reason, it gets rotated 90 clockwise. How can I fix this? My code is below

```
var imgOrientation = oImage.imageOrientation
var imgScale = oImage.scale


let originalImage = CIImage(image: oImage)

var filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffect"+arr[sender.tag-1000])
filter.setDefaults()
filter.setValue(originalImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

var outputImage = filter.outputImage
var newImage = UIImage(CIImage:outputImage, scale:imgScale, orientation:imgOrientation)


cameraStill.image = newImage
```

Comment: What is `oImage`? Is the image coming from the Camera Roll? In other words, is this a photo that the user took in portrait orientation? If so, how did you obtain it?

Comment: What is `cameraStill`? You cannot convert a CIImage to a usable UIImage merely by calling `init(CIImage:...)`.

Comment: oImage is an image the user took with his camera and cameraStill is a UIImageView which displays the image.

Comment: But how / when did you obtain the image from the camera roll? My answer will depend upon this.

Comment: So you are actually seeing the image in your image view? Even though a UIImage generated from `init(CIImage:)` is not suitable for direct display in an image view?

Comment: I obtain the image from taking from a custom avcamera instance which captures the picture. Why aren't UIImages suited to display? How can I make it suitable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the problem is this line:

```
var newImage = UIImage(CIImage:outputImage, scale:imgScale, orientation:imgOrientation)
```

That is not how you render a filter into a UIImage. What you want to do is call `CIContext(options: nil)` to get a CIContext, and then send that CIContext the message `createCGImage:fromRect:` to get a CGImage. Now turn that CGImage into a UIImage, and, as you do so, you can apply your orientation.

Comment: Hi @SpaceShroomies can you show the changes you have done? I'm having the same issue and not understand the solution

Comment: let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)
            let coreImage = CIImage(image: originalImage.image!)
            let filter = CIFilter(name: "\(CIFilterNames[i])" )
            filter!.setDefaults()
            filter!.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            let filteredImageData = filter!.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage
            let filteredImageRef = ciContext.createCGImage(filteredImageData, from: filteredImageData.extent)
            let imageForButton = UIImage(cgImage: filteredImageRef!);

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
let cgImage = self.context.createCGImage(filterOutputImage,
                                         from: cameraImage.extent)!

let orientation: UIImage.Orientation =
      currentCameraType == AVCaptureDevice.Position.front ?
           UIImage.Orientation.leftMirrored:
           UIImage.Orientation.right

let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage,
                    scale: 1.0,
                    orientation: orientation)
```

Comment: This creates distorted images