# why the image rotate 90 degrees after let cimg = CIImage(image: self.img)

Tags: swift, core-image

I'm processing image with apple core image,   when I translate a UIImage to CIImage, the image seems  rotate 90 degrees. Main code is like the following,

```
 struct PhotoDetailView: View {
    @Binding var img:UIImage
    var body: some View {
        
        print(self.img.size)
        let cimg = CIImage(image: self.img)
        print(cimg?.extent.size)
       
      let context = CIContext()
       
      let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectMono")!
    
        filter.setValue(cimg, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
      let result = filter.outputImage!
        print(result.extent.size)
```

print output:
(3024.0, 4032.0)
Optional((4032.0, 3024.0))
(4032.0, 3024.0)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30558516/image-rotating-after-cifilter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should keep the orientation info of a image

```
 let orientation = self.img.imageOrientation
 let cimg = CIImage(image: self.img)
 let context = CIContext()
 ...
 let img2 = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!, scale: 1.0, orientation: orientation)
```